# Select other window in Emacs at startup

Tags: emacs

Suppose I have two text files `A.txt` and `B.txt`. I choose to open both from Emacs using

```
emacs -no-splash -mm A.txt B.txt
```

Now the frame is split in two parts vertically, and file A is shown in the left window and file B in the right window. However file B is automatically selected by Emacs. I can move the point to the other window by entering `C-x o` or `ESC-: (other-window 1)`. But I would like to do this automatically, for instance at the command line or in the `.emacs` file.

I tried

```
emacs -no-splash -mm --eval `(other-window 1)` A.txt B.txt
```

but it did not work..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following seems to work: Enter in `.emacs` :

```
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook '(lambda () (other-window 1)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the following in your `~/.emacs` file:

```lisp
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook '(lambda () (select-first-buffer-in-list command-line-args)))

(defun select-first-buffer-in-list (list)
  (let (buffer)
    (while list
      (if (setq buffer (get-file-buffer (car list)))
      (progn (select-window (get-buffer-window buffer))
         (setq list nil))
    (setq list (cdr list))))))
```

It will check which of the command line parameters correspond to a buffer. It selects a window displaying the buffer of the first such parameter.

Comment: Thanks, but I could not get it to work.. Maybe because I am also using the `toggle-window-split` function, see http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ToggleWindowSplit ?

Comment: No, maybe that was not the issue after all.. I now removed the `toggle-window-split` from my `.emacs` and it still do not work.. (the windows are now split horizontally)

Comment: Shouldn't make a difference. What version of Emacs are you running? Could you put the above code in an otherwise empty file and use that instead of your regular .emacs file, please?

Comment: Do you get an error message, or does it just not show any difference at all?

Comment: I am using GNU Emacs 23.3.1 on Ubuntu 12.04. I now used an empty `.emacs` and it still do not work.. and I do not get any error messages in the Emacs messages buffer..

Comment: OK, I've tried it using GNU Emacs 24.3.1. on an older version of Ubuntu.

Comment: It works if I replace your code with: `(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook '(lambda () (other-window 1)))`

Comment: Perfect! Why don't you add that as a new answer and accept it?

Answer (score 0):

Independent of the order of the command line parameters, this approach finds the left-most, upper-most window and selects it. Put the following code in your .emacs file:

```lisp
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook '(lambda () (select-upper-left-window)))

(defun select-upper-left-window ()
  (let (window)
    (while (setq window (window-in-direction 'above nil t))
      (select-window window))
    (while (setq window (window-in-direction 'left nil t))
      (select-window window))))
```

Answer (score 0):

This would keep a single window with "B.txt"

```
emacs --find-file A.txt B.txt -Q -eval "(delete-other-windows)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you don't want to just reverse the order of the file names on the command line?